# Issue with passing the variable from SSJS to AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, content-builder

Used AMPScript and SSJS to generate an encrypted JSON message and pass this encryped JSON (payload) to the external system using a URL.   However, the last line in the below code is not picking the URL. Cannot understand what's going wrong here -

```
%%[ const crypto, var @data, @contentType, @payload, @encryptkeybase64, @authkeybase64,  @domain,  @response, @req, @resp, @encryptionKey, @authenticationKey, @cipher, @cipherText, @hmac, @base64Payload, @url, @iv, @ssconsole]%%


<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");

var contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
var encryptkeybase64  = '3kXLV1rnimLRdsdfsdfsdf2Wdd+/hYVTB/Dt6nnIk=';
var authkeybase64 = 'BKulGe3CTrweSHkrwerwerwerdNpFAeuuWhfevc4A=';
var domain = 'hughes.com';
const crypto = require('crypto');

var order   = {
                name : "Nishanth M",
                email : "sendanemailtonishanth@gmail.com",
                ref : "12345"
};

 var jsonSerializedOrder  = JSON.stringify(order);

// When you get the keys from Trustpilot, they are base64 encoded, so first we need to decode them
var encryptionKey = Buffer.from(encryptionKeyBase64, 'base64');
var authenticationKey = Buffer.from(authenticationKeyBase64, 'base64');

  // Generate a random initialization vector
var iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);

  // Encrypt our order
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', encryptionKey, iv);
var cipherText = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(jsonSerializedOrder, 'utf8'), cipher.final()]);

// Compute the HMAC
var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', authenticationKey).update(Buffer.concat([iv, cipherText])).digest();

// Base64 encode the IV + cipherText + HMAC
var base64Payload = Buffer.concat([iv, cipherText, hmac]).toString("base64");

// URL encode to get the final payload
var payload = encodeURIComponent(base64Payload);
var url = 'https://www.trustpilot.com/evaluate-bgl/' + domain + '?p=' + payload;  
  Write(url);
  console.log("Something happened");

  try {
  var req = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload);



    Write(req);

 if(req.StatusCode == 200) {
 var resp = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(req.Response[0]));
  Write(resp.Message);
  var accessToken = tokenResponse.accessToken;
   Write(accessToken);
 }
 } catch (ex) {
          Write("Exception Error: " + Stringify(ex));
          } 

  Variable.SetValue("@url",url);
</script>

<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@url)=%%">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the issue is NOT with SSJS or AMPscript! Please find the minified version of your code, where in I tested and it worked.

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");

var url = 'https://www.trustpilot.com/evaluate-bgl/' + 'testDOMAIN' + '?p=' + 'testPayload';  
  Write(url);
  Variable.SetValue("@OutputToConsole",url); //you cannot directly output to console, as this will output to server console NOT browser console
  Variable.SetValue("@url",url);
</script>

<script runat="client">
console.log(`%%=v(@OutputToConsole)=%%`); //Here this outputs to Browser console
</script>

<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@url)=%%">Test</a>
```

Note: I added the technique to log to browser console from SSJS, use this technique to debug your code.

Comment: Appreciate for taking time to look into this and thank you so much Vishal .. this worked !! As you rightly pointed out, this was always hitting server console before.

Answer (score 1):

Try it without the @:

```
Variable.SetValue("url",url);
```

Here’s the help article with an example: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_utilitiesVariableSetValue.htm

Comment: I tried it but the URL never receives the value.